# Do you need a VAO for each VBO?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

Currently, I have a collection of `RenderObject` classes which contains a texture, a VAO and a VBO. Drawing thousands of these objects incurs a performance penalty due to all the state switching and calls to `glDrawArrays` with small numbers of triangles.

So now I'm going to change my implementation so that I create a series of 1MiB VBOs (start with one, once it gets full, create a second 1MiB VBO and continue to fill that). Do I need a separate VAO for each VBO? The VBO already uses interleaved vertex data, so I'm not talking about using multiple VBOs for vertices, normals, texture coords, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think there may be some confusion. Vertex Attribs refers to the number of per vertex elements you can pass in with a single vertex (normals would be one, UVs another, etc). In your implementation, that is limited to 16 which you are most likely not going to exceed.

VAOs store the state information required to issue a single draw call. This includes storing which VBOs need to be bound for that call. Given that each VBO must be drawn in it's own separate draw call I would also think you need a VAO to store setup info for each.

Here is a good explanation:

http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial32/tutorial32.html

Comment: @MarkIngram I would keep it in the question for the sake of other readers.

Comment: I'm pretty much 100% that a VAO does not bind the VBO binding point (ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING), if you look at the VAO state table page in the 3.3 core spec pdf, it explicitly says on the next pp "not part of the VAO state". Also, https://twitter.com/id_aa_carmack/status/409495250646753280 

check https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec33.core.20100311.withchanges.pdf , check pp 281 and 282. 

I think the tutorial you linked just works because it sources the element array buffer which is the same one reused all the time, or because the element array buffer retains which VBO to use, not sure.